Color changes when hovering over another object
Problem is, I like that color and want to keep it, but when layered in front of another object with the same material, the object suddenly changes color from the desired one to dark blueish. I guess this is because it's glass? What do I do to prevent it from changing. 
Here are my nodes 

This is how glass works. See this example where glass gets greener the more layers the light has to pass through. You will need to weigh whether you want it to be realistically transparent or keep the same color despite being layered. I don't think you can do both at once.

@Jakemoyo how do I make it keep the same color? Switch off from glass bsdf completely?

So you want the glass to be transparent if it's superimposed over another glass part ? You can try the Is Transmission Ray output of the Light Path node I think

@Gorgious It should be transparent. It should  retain the color
